# dynamic T-SQL in stored procedure: error near keyword FROM. Code in new query run flawlessly

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, syntax-error, dynamic-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 (T-SQL) and have dynamic SQL code, which inserting into temporary table some data.
If I run code in new query window or PRINT code and then run in new query window everything is allright, BUT if I try to run this from stored procedure it throw error

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure users, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

If I remove line with `INSERT INTO #viewsTmp (webId, listId, viewName, viewTitle)`, code runs fine.
I have similar code above within same stored procedure and that code is fine.

Temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #viewsTmp 
(
    webId uniqueidentifier,
    listId uniqueidentifier,
    viewName NVARCHAR(128),
    viewTitle NVARCHAR(255)
)
```

variable @databaseName is declared as parameter of stored procedure

```
@databaseName NVARCHAR(255)
```

Code which is OK in new query window, but not ok if is runned from stored procedure:

```sql
SET @sql = N'
INSERT INTO #viewsTmp (webId, listId, viewName, viewTitle)
SELECT c.tp_WebId, c.tp_ID, b.LeafName, c.tp_Title
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT [ListId], [LeafName], [Type], [WebId]
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ListId ORDER BY DirName) AS RowNumber
          FROM ['+@databaseName+'].[dbo].[Docs]
          WHERE [LeafName] = ''users''
    ) AS a
    WHERE  [RowNumber] = 1 AND [Type] = 1
) AS b
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT [tp_WebId], [tp_ID], [tp_Title] FROM ['+@databaseName+'].[dbo].[Lists]) 
    AS c 
    ON b.ListId = c.tp_ID AND b.WebId = c.tp_WebId

';
--PRINT @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: If you are still stuck after checking out the provided answers I would suggest building this system up from scratch one step at a time, i.e. start with a simple, trivial query and confirm it works then add complexity a piece at a time. I just tried what you describe, but using a very simple query, and it worked just fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the query. The error looks like you had a comma at the end of the 2nd line `SELECT.... ,` at some stage

Comment: I suspect @databaseName is not getting passed / assigned correctly or has an invalid value.  In the sample you posted in the question you are not passing a value.

Comment: Thanks for ideas. I will check variable @databaseName and If it don't help I will try approach mentioned by Dale Burrel.

Comment: Database name is ok, I printed it before set @sql and it contained 'WSS_Content_800', so I will try decomposition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decomposed and composed code step by step with small modification as Dale Burrell advised....and code runs and don't runs. I didn't know what was that...and finally I discover one my mistake...

Code itself is ok, but I give @webId as parameter to call inner procedure which is called after code, and there was error. I had all rows with one webId, but exactly one row with another (exception in design) and I pass for this one row same webId as for another rows, and then in this subroutine error appeared. So error message was not for code above, but for some code in called procedure...

Oh my...5 hours of time....

In every way, thank you very much for trying help! 
I learned another thing about errors in T-SQL today.

Comment: Can someone mark it as something like "error between chair, computer and management studio 2008" or I don't know... but question is not relevant, because error is in not mentioned part of code...